# int? and int comparison when LEFT OUTER JOIN in Linq issue

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am working on a WinForms project which requires to use `Linq-To-Sql`. I have been able to create my DataContext using the `SqlMetal` tool, and make some queries. But right now I have a problem that I havent been able to solve.

I am trying to make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as following:

```
MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase(...);

 var query = from p in db.ParentTable
             join t in db.ChildTable on new {A = p.child_ID, B = p.OtherID}
             equals new {A = t.ID, B = t.OtherID} into j1
             from c in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                  ...
             };
```

When I write this query an error is raised at compile-time in the `join` word:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'

I know this error is caused by the comparison between `p.child_ID` and `t.ID` since `p.child_ID` is `int?` and `t.ID` is `int`. But, **How can I solve this? How can I perform the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` without having this error??**

`p.child_ID` is `int?` since this column is marked as `IS NULL` in `SQL`.

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you tried this... on new {p.child_ID.Value,...} I'm not sure if that would work.

Comment: i'd look up the `??` operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [GetValueOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx) method. It retrieves the value of the current Nullable object, or the object's default value.

In terms of your example :

```
var query = from p in db.ParentTable
            join t in db.ChildTable on new {A = p.child_ID.GetValueOrDefault(0), B = p.OtherID}
            equals new {A = t.ID, B = t.OtherID} into j1
            from c in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                ...
            };
```

If the p.child_ID become null than it will return 0. Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 4):

The first problem was that the property names should be the same as said *casperOne♦*, but the second problem is that you're comparing a *nullable-int*, `p.child_ID`,  with a *non-nullable-int*, `t.ID`. So you could use the *null-coalescing operator* in this way:

```
(int)(p.child_ID ?? default(int))
```

In this case returns `p.child_ID` if it isn't null else returns `default(int)`, that is `0`.

The query will be:

```
var query = from p in db.ParentTable
            join t in db.ChildTable on new {A = (int)(p.child_ID ?? default(T)), B = p.OtherID}
            equals new {A = t.ID, B = t.OtherID} into j1
            from c in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
               //...
            };
```

Comment: Thanks. could be shortened as  (p.child_ID ?? 0)