# LINQ LEFT JOIN on Nullable<int>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join

I have two tables below:

```
Project(
    ProjectID       INT,
    Name            VARCHAR(200),
    AssignedUserID  INT NULL
)
User(
    UserID      INT,
    LastName    VARCHAR(50),
    FirstName   VARCHAR(50)
)
```

I'm using Entity Framework Database-First approach. So in my Model:

```
Class Project{
    public int ProjectID;
    public string Name;
    public Nullable<int> AssignedUserID;
}

Class User{
    public int UserID;
    public string LastName;
    public string FirstName;
}
```

I want to query all `PROJECT` and its assigned user:

```
SELECT
    p.ProjectID,
    p.Name,
    u.LastName,
    u.FirstName
FROM Project p
LEFT JOIN Users u ON u.UserID = p.AssignedUserID
```

Translating to Linq:

```
var projectDetails =
    from p in context.Project
    join u in context.User
        on p.AssignedUserID equals u.UserID into lj
    from x in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {
            ProjectID = p.ProjectID,
            ProjectName = p.Name,
            UserLastName = u.LastName,
            UserFirstName = u.FirstName
        }
```

However, I'm getting an error:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. 
>   Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

I've tried both solutions on **[int? and int comparison when LEFT OUTER JOIN in Linq issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411172/int-and-int-comparison-when-left-outer-join-in-linq-issue)**, but still it's giving me these errors:

Using the solution: `(int)(p.AssignedUserID ?? default(int))`

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(Int32)'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Using the solution `GetValueOrDefault()`:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   GetValueOrDefault(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

How do you do `LEFT JOIN` on `Nullable<int>` and `int`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what I do when I have to do a Join on a nullable field

Original Linq:

```
var projectDetails =
    from p in context.Project
    join u in context.User
        on p.AssignedUserID equals u.UserID into lj
    from x in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {
            ProjectID = p.ProjectID,
            ProjectName = p.Name,
            UserLastName = u.LastName,
            UserFirstName = u.FirstName
        }
```

Modified Linq:

```
var projectDetails =
    from p in context.Project
    join u in context.User
        on new {User = p.AssignedUserID} equals new {User = (int?)u.UserID} into lj
    from x in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {
            ProjectID = p.ProjectID,
            ProjectName = p.Name,
            UserLastName = x.LastName,
            UserFirstName = x.FirstName
        }
```

The problem is that you are trying to join an int with an int?, which is giving you the error message, cast the int of the UserId to a nullable int, will solve your issue.

Comment: Still getting this error: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: Can you show all the code, because it seems that something else is going on

Comment: I'm sorry, your answer works. There are some call to `Convert.Int32` on the `select` part that's causing the error. Thanks for your time.

Comment: In the select you can use prop = (x.Field.HasValue) ? x.Field.Value : [defaultValue for null]

Comment: In EF Core 2, this method results in a Customer Side Evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

If any of the columns in join is of `Nullable` type, we need to fetch itts actual value using `.Value`, something like this:-

```
    join u in context.User
        on p.AssignedUserID.Value equals u.UserID into lj
```

Or you can also do this:-

```
join u in context.User
            on new { p.AssignedUserID } equals new { AssignedUserID = u.UserID } into lj
```

Comment: You need to have `new {AssignedUserID = p.AssignedUserID } equals new { AssignedUserID = u.UserID }`

Comment: @JenishRabadiya - Nope that's not mandatory. Both will infer the same name as `AssignedUserID `

Comment: @RahulSingh: still getting the same error: `The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'`. It wouldn't even allow me to compile.

Comment: @RahulSingh I read it here on the stackover flow thread that it is mandatory. might be I am getting wrong. here is so thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184019/the-type-of-one-of-the-expressions-in-the-join-clause-is-incorrect-in-entity-fra

Comment: I'm sorry, your answer works. There are some call to Convert.Int32 on the select part that's causing the error. Thanks for your time. +1

Answer (score 2):

You're actually doing a lot of the work that EF is supposed to be doing for you (this happens alot, in particular with `join`).

You need a navigation property on your `Project` class, not just the FK you have now:

**EDIT**: updated the following POCOs for EF Database-First (i.e. using `partial` classes).

```
// generated code
public partial class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? AssignedUserId { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

// your code
public partial class Project
{
    [ForeignKey("AssignedUserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Note that you have to remember to add the `partial` keyword on the generated version of the `Project` class each time you regenerate it, but this is still better, because — by keeping your additions in a separate `partial` class declaration — the `partial` keyword is the *only* thing you'll have to remember to change in the generated class.

So your query is simply the following:

```
var projectDetails = from p in context.Projects
                     select new
                     {
                         p.ProjectId,
                         p.Name,
                         p.User.LastName,
                         p.User.FirstName
                     };
```

Let's see what this looks like:

```
Console.WriteLine(projectDetails.ToString());
```

This yields the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[ProjectId] AS [ProjectId],
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Extent2].[LastName] AS [LastName],
    [Extent2].[FirstName] AS [FirstName]
    FROM [Projects] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Users] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[AssignedUserId] = [Extent2].[UserId]
```

Which would appear to be exactly what you want.

Comment: Great answer +1, but the tables don't have an explicit FK relationship. Is there any other way without adding the FK?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? You already had `AssignedUserId` as a property, heck, as a field in the underlying schema ... is that not a Foreign Key? All I did was add a navigation property which is the whole point of using Entity Framework ... without that, I don't why you wouldn't just use LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: No, it's an FK, not declared as one.

Comment: The use of the `ForeignKeyAttribute` doesn't make it one in the schema ... it's just telling EF how `User` relates to `AssignedUserId`. I started with your original model, used it to create the database, added my navigation property `User`, and it ran against the same database without modification.

Comment: Oh, so I just need to add the `ForeignKeyAttribute` in the class generated by EF/

Comment: oh, right, Database-First ... I'll update my answer (TL;DR - yes, add `ForeignKeyAttribute` in generated class).

Comment: It's okay. I get the idea. Thank you very much!